# GraphQL schema From Leon how to get Flight crew Duty status

Tags: curl, leon

I try to fetch flight schedule details from Leon using GraphQL.I need crew member duty status such as {start,continous,end} for each crew in flight.I have checked CrewPanelActivities Object.But crew duty status not foud.Please you provide the Object to get crew duty status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work with this, tested in postman

```
{
  "query": "query GetCrewPanelPositioning($crewMemberNid: CrewMemberNid!, $start: DateTime!, $end: DateTime!, $filterToggle: CrewPanelFilterToggle!) { crewPanel { activities(timeInterval: {start: $start, end: $end}, loginList: [$crewMemberNid], filterToggle: $filterToggle, includeDrafts: true, showOptions: true) { positionings { trNid loginNid startTimeIso endTimeIso startAirport { code { icao iata } name city country } endAirport { code { icao iata } name city country } hasDraft positioningNid note name isOption ticketNumber type aocSource aocNid draftStatus trip { tripNid } isRebook } } } }",
  "variables": {
    "crewMemberNid": 1053311, 
    "start": "2024-02-01",
    "end": "2024-03-01",
    "filterToggle": {
      "baseNid":1, // Hypothetical value, replace with actual baseNid required by your filter
      "aptCode": "IATA",
      "timeZone": "UTC"
    }
  }
}
```

don't forget to set variables